# How to print a particular sentence containing number out of multiple sentences in python 3.9?

Tags: python, python-3.x

There is a paragraph stored in a string containing multiple lines, how can I print the lines containing a number in them.
My code yet-

```
text="Hello there, How are you. Today I bought 3 books. What did you do today. I heard you are coming 1 day later."
print(text.split('.'))
```

Output-

```
['Hello there, How are you', ' Today I bought 3 books', ' What did you do today', ' I heard you are coming 1 day later', '']
```

What I want is that only the sentences with numbers in them should be printed

like in this example, 'Today I bought 3 books' and 'I heard you are coming one day later'.

Also, kindly give explanation on how you did it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you share an example of what you have, what you want and what you have written youself so far? If your text is stored in a string you can e.g. use `text.split('.')` to seperate the sentences.

Comment: Look about : split text in lines, iterate over lines, check if value in string

Comment: Basically, I'm making a project in which only the sentences with number will get printed out of the whole paragraph(stored in a string).

Comment: After splitting how to choose to print the lines containing a number?

Comment: If you update your questions with more details, it will be easier to give you a good answer.

Comment: How about using google with **"split text into lines python site:stackoverflow.com"**  and **"find number in string python site:stackoverflow.com"** and use what you find to build a prototype. By guess: almost 99.99% of all things you as a new pythonista are going to asked are already covered multiple times on SO - just find and use them. That is why SO is a Q&A site - it has most of your answers already.

Comment: @PatrickArtner I already tried and got results like how to extract numbers from string, etc.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `split()` function to get the sentences from the paragraph. It will return a list of sentences. Iterate over the list using for loop and then use another for loop inside the previous for loop to iterate over the characters of the sentence. Then check if the character is a digit using `isdigit()` function and print that sentence.

Here is the code for the same. Hope it will be helpful.

```
text = "Python is a popular programming language. It was created by Guido van Rossum, and released in 1991. From web development to machine learning to data science, Python is the language for you."  

sentences = text.split('.')  # split string into list of partial strings at full stops
for s in sentences:
    for char in s:
        if char.isdigit():
            print(s)   # we found a number, print whole sentence
            break      # break for char in s - loop and continue with next s
```

**Output:**

```
It was created by Guido van Rossum, and released in 1991
```

Comment: What is s in the code?

Comment: @SoumyaRaj   `for s in sentence:` ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner yes

Comment: Can anyone give clarification what is s in `for s in sentence`?

Comment: @SoumyaRaj   s is a variable that will store a particular sentence during iterations and its value will change after each iteration.